# Manjaro update error: failed to update core (unable to lock database)

Tags: archlinux, kde-plasma, manjaro, pacman-package-manager

I am a noob on an i5 desktop.  I could not update my system. Terminal reads as follows, after I type and enter "sudo pacman -Syu"

```
[sudo] password for user-name: ********
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed to update core (unable to lock database)
error: failed to update extra (unable to lock database)
error: failed to update community (unable to lock database)
error: failed to update multilib (unable to lock database)
error: failed to synchronize all databases
```

Help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sorry, this is already covered in the wiki...

```
sudo rm /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
```

[pacman-ArchWiki: "Failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)" error](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#.22Failed_to_init_transaction_.28unable_to_lock_database.29.22_error)

Comment: for me this file even does not exist! and still it give's me  error... what i should to do?

Comment: Check your hooks as well — if one of your pacman hooks calls pacman itself, that will also cause this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already deleted `/var/lib/pacman/db.lck`, like OP posted, and still got the same problem, try this:

```
sudo rm /var/tmp/pamac/dbs/db.lck
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by quitting **Software Update** program from task manager.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hit this issue a few times on Manjaro and the answer was never to delete the database lock

1. `sudo rm -r /var/tmp/pamac` to delete the temp package manager directory
2. `sudo pacman -Syu` [to](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman#Upgrading_packages) synchronize the repository databases and update system packages
3. Quit out of the package manager app/GUI and reload. All should be back to normal.